# Директивы препроцессора, pt2 и макросы в header файле

Tags: c++, препроцессор

Есть header с набором макросов, переопределяющих имена функций, но почему то работает только первый #ifdef, а все остальные не подключаются и вне зависимости от того, какой тип переменной я определяю, подставляется всегда  только вариант для INTEGER :(
Что я делаю не так?

UPD: #pragma once, #ifndef Macro_h и #define Macro_h надо убрать, тогда все работает!

header

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Macro_h
#define Macro_h

#ifdef INTEGER
#undef populate
#undef display
#undef minPos
#undef maxPos
#undef sort
#undef editAll
#define populate populateInt
#define display displayInt
#define minPos minPosInt
#define maxPos maxPosInt
#define sort sortInt
#define editAll editAllInt

#elif FLOAT
#undef populate
#undef display
#undef minPos
#undef maxPos
#undef sort
#undef editAll
#define populate populateFloat
#define display displayFloat
#define minPos minPosFloat
#define maxPos maxPosFloat
#define sort sortFloat
#define editAll editAllFloat

#elif CHAR
#undef populate
#undef display
#undef minPos
#undef maxPos
#undef sort
#undef editAll
#define populate populateChar
#define display displayChar
#define minPos minPosChar
#define maxPos maxPosChar
#define sort sortChar
#define editAll editAllChar
#endif

#endif // !Macro_h
```

header

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Function_h
#define Function_h

void populateInt(int *arr, int size);
void displayInt(int *arr, int size);
void minPosInt(int *arr, int size, int &pos);
void maxPosInt(int *arr, int size, int &pos);
void sortInt(int *arr, int left, int right);
void editAllInt(int *arr, int size);

void populateFloat(float *arr, int size);
void displayFloat(float *arr, int size);
void minPosFloat(float *arr, int size, int &pos);
void maxPosFloat(float *arr, int size, int &pos);
void sortFloat(float *arr, int left, int right);
void editAllFloat(float *arr, int size);

void populateChar(char *arr, int size);
void displayChar(char *arr, int size);
void minPosChar(char *arr, int size, int &pos);
void maxPosChar(char *arr, int size, int &pos);
void sortChar(char *arr, int left, int right);
void editAllChar(char *arr, int size);

#endif // !Function_h
```

функции

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Function.h"

using namespace std;

//populate
void populateInt(int *arr, int size) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++)
        *(arr + i) = rand() % 100 + 1;
}

void populateFloat(float *arr, int size) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        int a = (1 + rand() % 100);
        int b = (1 + rand() % 100);
        *(arr + i) = (float) a * 1.0 / b * 1.0;
    }
}

void populateChar(char *arr, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++)
        *(arr + i) = (char)(rand() % 25 + 97);
}

//display
void displayInt(int *arr, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++)
        cout << " " << *(arr + i);
    cout << endl;
}

void displayFloat(float *arr, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    cout.precision(2);
    for (i; i < size; i++)
        cout << " " << *(arr + i);
    cout << endl;
}

void displayChar(char *arr, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++)
        cout << " " << *(arr + i);
    cout << endl;
}

//min
void minPosInt(int *arr, int size, int &pos) {
    int min = *(arr), i = 1;
    pos = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) < min) {
            min = *(arr + i);
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}

void minPosFloat(float *arr, int size, int &pos) {
    float min = *(arr);
    pos = 0;
    int i = 1;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) < min) {
            min = *(arr + i);
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}

void minPosChar(char *arr, int size, int &pos) {
    char min = *(arr);
    int i = 1;
    pos = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) < min) {
            min = *(arr + i);
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}

//max
void maxPosInt(int *arr, int size, int &pos) {
    int max = *(arr), i = 1;
    pos = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) > max) {
            max = *(arr + i);
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}

void maxPosFloat(float *arr, int size, int &pos) {
    float max = *(arr);
    pos = 0;
    int i = 1;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) > max) {
            max = *(arr + i);
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}

void maxPosChar(char *arr, int size, int &pos) {
    float max = *(arr);
    int i = 1;
    pos = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) > max) {
            max = *(arr + i);
            pos = i;
        }
    }
}

//sort
void sortInt(int *arr, int left, int right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2, i = left, j = right;
    int temp, pivot = *(arr + mid);
    while (i <= j) {
        while (*(arr + i) < pivot)
            i++;
        while (*(arr + j) > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            temp = *(arr + i);
            *(arr + i) = *(arr + j);
            *(arr + j) = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (i < right)
        sortInt(arr, i, right);
    if (j > left)
        sortInt(arr, left, j);
}

void sortFloat(float *arr, int left, int right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2, i = left, j = right;
    float temp, pivot = *(arr + mid);
    while (i <= j) {
        while (*(arr + i) < pivot)
            i++;
        while (*(arr + j) > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            temp = *(arr + i);
            *(arr + i) = *(arr + j);
            *(arr + j) = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (i < right)
        sortFloat(arr, i, right);
    if (j > left)
        sortFloat(arr, left, j);
}

void sortChar(char *arr, int left, int right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2, i = left, j = right;
    char temp, pivot = *(arr + mid);
    while (i <= j) {
        while (*(arr + i) < pivot)
            i++;
        while (*(arr + j) > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            temp = *(arr + i);
            *(arr + i) = *(arr + j);
            *(arr + j) = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (i < right)
        sortChar(arr, i, right);
    if (j > left)
        sortChar(arr, left, j);
}

//edit
void editAllInt(int *arr, int size) {
    int currVal, newVal, i;
    cout << "Insert curent value ";
    cin >> currVal;
    cout << "Insert new value ";
    cin >> newVal;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(arr + i) == currVal ? *(arr + i) = newVal : *(arr + i);
}

void editAllFloat(float *arr, int size) {
    float currVal, newVal;
    int i;
    cout << "Insert curent value ";
    cin >> currVal;
    cout << "Insert new value ";
    cin >> newVal;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(arr + i) == currVal ? *(arr + i) = newVal : *(arr + i);
}

void editAllChar(char *arr, int size) {
    char currVal, newVal;
    int i;
    cout << "Insert curent value ";
    cin >> currVal;
    cout << "Insert new value ";
    cin >> newVal;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(arr + i) == currVal ? *(arr + i) = newVal : *(arr + i);
}
```

исходник

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Function.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
#define INTEGER
#include "Macro.h"
    int *arr, size, pos = 0;
    cout << "Insert array size ";
    cin >> size;
    arr = new int[size];
    cout << "Int:" << endl;
    populate (arr, size);
    display (arr, size);
    minPos (arr, size, pos);
    cout << "Minpos: " << pos + 1 << ", min = " << *(arr + pos) << endl;
    maxPos (arr, size, pos);
    cout << "Maxpos: " << pos + 1 << ", max = " << *(arr + pos) << endl;
    sort (arr, 0, size - 1); 
    cout << "Sort: ";
    display (arr, size);
    editAll (arr, size);
    display (arr, size);
    delete[] arr;
#undef INTEGER

#define FLOAT
#include "Macro.h"
    cout << "Float" << endl;
    float *fArr;
    fArr = new float[size];
    populate (fArr, size);
    display (fArr, size);
    minPos (fArr, size, pos);
    cout << "Minpos: " << pos + 1 << ", min = " << fArr[pos] << endl;
    maxPos (fArr, size, pos);
    cout << "Maxpos: " << pos + 1 << ", max = " << fArr[pos] << endl;
    sort (fArr, 0, size - 1);
    cout << "Sort: ";
    display (fArr, size);
    editAll (fArr, size);
    display (fArr, size);
    delete[] fArr;
#undef FLOAT

#define CHAR
#include "Macro.h"
    cout << "Char" << endl;
    char *chArr;
    chArr = new char[size];
    populate (chArr, size);
    display (chArr, size);
    minPos (chArr, size, pos);
    cout << "Minpos: " << pos + 1 << ", min = " << chArr[pos] << endl;
    maxPos (chArr, size, pos);
    cout << "Maxpos: " << pos + 1 << ", max = " << chArr[pos] << endl;
    sort (chArr, 0, size - 1);
    cout << "Sort: ";
    display (chArr, size);
    editAll (chArr, size);
    display (chArr, size);
    delete[] chArr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, текстуально код будет выглядеть более красивым, если сделать несколько заголовочных `Macro.h` (по одному для каждого типа, например, `FloatMacro.h`, `CharMacro.h` и т.д.) и включать их. Т.е. вместо `#define INTEGER  \n #include "Macro.h"` писать просто `#include "IntegerMacro.h`

Comment: Однако, сама идея functions ovrloadind, да еще и реализованная подобным образом, плоха для практического программирования (хотя и весьма популярна ныне).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в заголовочном файле присутствует include guard `#ifndef Macro_h` Соответственно после первого включения этого заголовочного файла `Macro_h` уже будет объявлено и повторно разбирать тело заголовочного файла препроцессор не будет.

Ну а вообще это все не нужно. Вам стоит познакомиться с шаблонами которые как раз позволяют переиспользовать код для разных типов. Вместо копипасты кода в `main` можно было бы запилить одну шаблонную функцию:

```
template<typename T> void
Work(void)
{
    T *arr{};
    size_t size{};
    size_t pos{};
    cout << "Insert array size ";
    cin >> size;
    arr = new T[size];
    …

int main()
{
    Work<int>();
    Work<float>();
    ...
```

Comment: О шаблонах я знаю, спасибо, но постановка задачи именно такова, что я должна создать функции под каждый тип данных и переопределить их имена при помощи макросов. Я бы тоже сделала шаблонами, меньше головной боли в разы.

Comment: @Светлана Ну тогда можно убрать include guard. Также можно не дублировать блоки `#undef populate #undef display`. А вообще задача - просто жесть...

Comment: Я так и сделала, спасибо вам огромное за совет! Наконец то она работает как надо!

Answer (score 0):

Надо примерно так:

```
   #if defined(_MY1)
   ...
   #elif defined(_MY2)
   ...
   #endif
```